# ASP.Net WebClient Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, file-upload, sp-send-dbmail

I am trying to send e-mail with attachments using SQL Server's database mail from my ASP.NET website and thus I figured I need to upload the file that is to be attached, to the server where the database is hosted.

The thing is, the my ASP.NET website's web server and the database are on different servers. The servers are also on different domains.

Here is what I have done so far:

I have shared a folder under the path `\\myservername\myfolder\` in the server where the database is hosted. The following code is to upload the selected file into the shared folder.

This is the ASP.NET webforms file upload control in the .aspx page:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="fu" runat="server" />
```

This is in my codebehind:

```
 NetworkCredential myCred = new NetworkCredential("myusername", "mypassword", "mydomain");

 using (WebClient webclient = new WebClient())
 {
     webclient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
     webclient.Credentials = myCred;

     if (fu.HasFile)
     {
         string path = string.Empty;
         string ServerPath = "\\\\myservername\\myfolder\\";
         string filename = Path.GetFileName(fu.FileName);
         string TempPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), filename);
         fu.SaveAs(TempPath);
         path = Path.Combine(ServerPath, filename);
         Uri ServerFile = new Uri(path);
         webclient.UploadFile(ServerFile, "PUT", TempPath);
         return path;
     }
     else
     {
         return "";
     }
 }
```

The code works perfectly fine if I have logged in to the shared folder before on the server hosting the website's web server, or if I have logged in to the shared folder prior on my local machine when debugging the website.

However if I had not logged in beforehand, it will throw the exception message:
`Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.`

I have tried to resolve this issue by adding in the network credentials which include my username, password and domain for the web client but the same error occurs even though I am sure that I have passed in the correct credentials.

Is there a method to workaround this issue or am I misunderstanding something here? I do not quite get what the problem is. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered using impersonation in ASP.NET for saving the files to your network? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh507fc5.aspx

Comment: I have tried using impersonation, it works using an account with same domain as the server/machine running the website. Using a different domain account gives me this error: `Could not create Windows user token from the credentials specified in the config file. Error from the operating system 'Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.`